# What happens if the Ground plane is expanded/poured in the VCC/Power layer in the multilayered PCB design? Is that recommended?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, noise, pcb-layers

I just wanted to know what are the advantage and disadvantage expanding the ground plane in the VCC/power plane in the multi layered PCB.

Below is the 10 layered PCB stackup:-

TOP,
Gnd,
Sig 1,
Sig 2,
VCC1,
VCC2,
Sig 3,
Sig 4,
Gnd,
Bottom,

I want to expand the GND plane in VCC1 and VCC2 layer. The reason behind is to provide solid ground reference for the signal present in the sig 2 and sig 3 layer.

Comment: At what frequency does this board work?

Comment: Its a high speed card and its operating frequency is 8 GHz.

Comment: I think you can add as long as you don't create capacitance between layers

Comment: May I know how can I decide this.. is there any calculation involved?

Comment: I don't know much about the calculation or rule of thumb. I haven't encountered this type of problem yet.